# how to create a python series of an integer of length n in a loop

Tags: python

I am looping through a range

```
Loopnumber = []

for i in range(2):
   series1 = [10/01/2017, 30,10,2017, 21/11/2017]
   loopnumber = ?

Loopnumber.extend(loopnumber)
```

I wish to create a series of same length as series 1 which a datetime series, and which is of value i and every time the loop runs the values of i are appended to a vector called loopnumber

expected output is

```
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
```

in this case expected output is

Comment: `loopnumber = len(series) * [i]`?

Comment: If you want to increase/extend `loopnumber` *inside* the loop, it becomes `loopnumber.extend(len(series) * [i])`, but since you're doing something similar outside the loop, I'm not sure if that's what you want. But you get the idea how to make a list with the same element repeated n times.

Comment: Since you know before the loop what the outcome will be, why not just generate it directly (i.e. not in the loop): `import numpy as np` and then `np.repeat(range(3),len(series1))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear *why* you need this, but you can extend a list *within* your `for` loop. Note also you need `range(3)` to iterate 3 times.

```
loop_list = []

for i in range(3):
    series1 = ['10/01/2017', '30,10,2017', '21/11/2017']
    loop_list.extend([i]*len(series1))

print(loop_list)

[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
```